# Parent without child sql

Tags: sql

I have a requirement wherein i have to identify the parent record which has no corresponding child record. for e.g.

Parent Table has 6 records : A, B, C, D, E, F
Child Table1 has reference to : A, B
Child Table2 has reference to : C, D

So how should i form my query which will return me the result E and F. As both these values are not used in any of the child tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lacks a little information for a compelte example, but i assume that you have parentID in childTable1 and childTable2, and id in parentTable.

This should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM parentTable p
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
              SELECT 1
              FROM childTable1 c1
              WHERE c1.parentId = p.id)
     AND NOT EXISTS(
              SELECT 1
              FROM childTable2 c1
              WHERE c1.parentId = p.id)
```

Comment: If you want to validate multiple columns, you can add another validation to the WHERE clause: `OR c1.anotherCol = p.id`